# Scala program using futures is not terminating

Tags: scala, concurrency

I am trying to learn concurrency in Scala and using Scala futures to generate a dataset with random string. I want to create an application which should generate a file with any number of records and it should be scalable.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutorService, Executors}
import scala.util.{Failure, Random, Success}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

  object datacreator {

    implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = new ExecutionContext {

    val threadPool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)

    def execute(runnable: Runnable) {
      threadPool.submit(runnable)
    }

    def reportFailure(t: Throwable) {}
  }

  def getRecord : String = {
    "Random string"
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val filename = args(0)
    val number_of_records = args(1)
    val file_Object = new FileWriter(filename, true)

    val data: Future[Iterable[String]] = Future {
      for (i <- 1 to number_of_records.toInt)
        yield getRecord
    }

    val result = data.map{
      result => result.foreach(record => file_Object.write(record))
    }

    result.onComplete{
          case Success(value) => {
            println("Success")
            file_Object.close()
          }
          case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}
```

I am facing the following issues:

1. When I am running the program using SBT it is writing results to the file but not terminating as going in infinite mode.

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/cw0155/PersonalProjects/datagen/project
[info] Loading settings for project datagen from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to datagenerator (in build file:/Users/cw0155/PersonalProjects/datagen/)
[info] running com.generator.DataGenerator xyz.csv 100
Success
  | => datagen / Compile / runMain 255s
```

2. When I am running the program using Jar as:

`scala -cp target/scala-2.13/datagenerator_2.13-0.1.jar com.generator.DataGenerator "pqr.csv" "1000"`
It is waiting infinite time and not writing to the file.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: First clue: what type is `result`? (i.e. `Future` of what?)

Comment: Yes, it is Future[Unit]

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

bar.scala

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future, ExecutionContext}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import java.io.FileWriter
object bar {
  def getRecord: String = "Random string\n"
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val filename = args(0)
    val number_of_records = args(1)
    val data: Future[Iterable[String]] = Future {
      for (i <- 1 to number_of_records.toInt)
        yield getRecord
    }
    val file_Object = new FileWriter(filename, true)
    val result      = data.map( r => r.foreach(record => file_Object.write(record)) )
    result.onComplete {
      case Success(value) =>
        println("Success")
        file_Object.close()
      case Failure(e) =>
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    Await.result( result, 10.second )
  }
}
```

Your original version gave me the expected output when I ran it like so

```
bash-3.2$ scala bar.scala /dev/fd/1 10
Success
Random string
Random string
Random string
Random string
Random string
Random string
Random string
Random string
Random string
Random string
```

However without the `Await.result` your program can exit before the future finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)  How to know the right value of timeout as the number of records can vary let's say it might be some billions. how to do without await? I also see you have imported the global execution context while I am creating one and that is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Ajit K'sagar Unfortunately, there is no good answer what is proper timeout, it depends on the context of your problem. As one of the options you can use `scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf` - infinite duration, meaning your app will exit only when this future will be finished, without any time limitations at all. Or use maximum timeout which is acceptable for you - say 1 hour.